# Access app_context from another task in Quart

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, quart

My Quart app is created with a create_app factory method.

I also have a third party library incorporated as an additional task via the create_task method.

I pass a callback function to this library which updates my database (via SQLAlchemy).
Unfortunately this does not work and raises the exception:

**"Attempt to access app outside of a relevant context"**

Pushing the app context does not work:

`from quart import current_app as app`

`async with app.app_context():`

Looking at Quarts Context Documentation: https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/contexts.html 
it is obvious why, because the app does not exist in the third party task.

> Both of these contexts exist per request and allow the global proxies
>   current_app, request, etc… to be resolved. **Note that these contexts
>   are task local, and hence will not exist if a task is spawned by
>   ensure_future or create_task.**

Does anyone has any other solution to get the app context from another task?

**Edit**
It still won't work. I am using Quart 0.10.0.
A more verbose example of my app looks like this:

```py
from app import create_app

from third_party import ThirdParty

third_party = ThirdParty(loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())
app = create_app()

@app.before_serving
async def startup():
    async with app.app_context() as app_context:
        await third_party.start()


@app.after_serving
async def shutdown():
    await third_party.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The ThirdParty is basically this:

```py
class ThirdParty:
    async def start(self):
        self.loop.create_task(self.run())

    async def run(self):
        while True:
            await self.wait_for_trigger()
            # executes my callback function
            await self.custom_callback_func()
```

my callback function is in another module and I pass to the third_party instance:

```py
from quart import current_app as app

async def custom_callback_func():
    async with app.app_context:
        # update_my database
        # raises "Attempt to access app outside of a relevant context"
```

If the app_context is automatically copied to created tasks from a task with the app context, why is my example not working?

await third_party.start() inside the with app_context statement calls loop.create_task(run()) which runs my assigned callback function. So why is there no app_context inside this callback available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must be using a 0.6.X version of Quart? If so the `copy_current_app_context` (from quart.ctx) can be used to explicitly copy the context into a new task. For example,

```
task = asyncio.ensure_future(copy_current_app_context(other_task_function)())
```

See also [this short documentation snippet](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/contexts.html#tasks-and-contexts). Note though that it is written with Quart >= 0.7 which should automatically copy the context between tasks.

**Edit:**
Following an update to the question.

I think you are best placed passing the `app` instance and using it directly, rather than using `current_app` in the task. This is because there is no app context after `before_serving` and before the first request. This may change in Quart though, see this [issue](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart/issues/299).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time answering. Could you have another look at my Edit? I am using Quart 0.10.0 and as far as I understand you the app context should be copied to my created task. Thank you for Quart btw :)